# Count how many values are same in database and increase if number reached

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database with poule ID's for a tournament. Now I wish to have no more than 4 teams in 1 poule (id). So if 4 teams are in poule_id 1 it needs to put them in poule_id 2 and if there are 4 in poule_id 2 they need to go to poule_id 3 etc.

[poule table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pBe8.png)

I've only selected the poule_id's so far.

```
   $sql = "SELECT poule_id FROM `tbl_teams` WHERE poule_id IS NOT NULL";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $teams = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($teams);
```

Which gets me:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["poule_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["poule_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["poule_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["poule_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["poule_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["poule_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    ["poule_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(1) {
    ["poule_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(1) {
    ["poule_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Now I'm stuck as I can't find how to count how many teams there are in poule_id 1.

Sorry for being scrub.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use `COUNT()` or an `if(condition) >=X` . Many ways to do this. Possibly adding a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

So long as your insertion logic remains the same you can use something like:

```
select if(
    exists(select max(poule_id) from tbl_teams group by poule_id having count(poule_id) < 4), 
    max(poule_id), 
    max(poule_id) +1
) use_id 
from tbl_teams;
```

to get the poule_id you should use (as alias use_id) for your next insertion. So long as you only use this code to get your next id you should be fine. Of course test in your specific use case to ensure it does as you expect.

Comment: I should add this returns `null` on an empty table, so you might need to test for that for your first entry.